# Modem COM port retrieval from the device manager

Tags: windows, winforms, winapi, device-driver

I'm looking for retrieving the Modem COM port information available in the device manager. When any 2g/3g dongles are connected to a pc, they get detected by the OS and registered as a modem. In the device properties, we have the modem tab. By clicking on the modem tab, we get the com port information. and we wanted to retrieve this modem information through any in-built app or a piece of code.

have already tried devcon.exe (provided by Microsoft) and it doesn't help us.it just retrieves the HW id of the modem, but not the COM port details etc.. if anyone has an idea on this, please help me with this.

Regards
Siva

Answer (score 0):

You can find all com ports listed in this registry key

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\DEVICEMAP\SERIALCOMM
```

Comment: thx for response. yes, we can find all the com ports in this place. however, in our requirement, we need to exactly send the commands on the COM port thats under the MODEM option. Also, with the name shown in the output of this command, we are not able distinguish between the different make of dongles.

Comment: Use the setup api thouse api's are used by device manager to enumarate all devices. What language are you coding in  ? there must be a library aviable for Delphi i know it exists 100%

Comment: ok.. thx.. will see the delphi library once.... the framework is created using java, vc++, c#